# Does DocOpt support the @FILE syntax for supplying a file with additional CLI options?

Tags: docopt

The title says it all! I can't seem to find this in any of the documentation nor on any other sites/SO questions.

What I want to do is when calling my program, specify a file that contains more CLI options. It is supported in some UNIX programs (like `ar`) and is handy on systems where there is a limit on how long your command line can be. Does DocOpt support this?

What I want to do:

`myProg -d --process-all --some-other-opt "hello" @additionalOptions.txt`

Where `additionalOptions.txt` contains something like:

> -g
>   --name "Sarah"
>   --name "Caleb"
>   --name "Sharen"
>   --name "Matt"
>   ... # However many more

Comment: I am specifically using DocOpt-Cpp. Hopefully that shouldn't matter since if it is available in DocOpt, it can be easily ported to DocOpt-Cpp.

Answer (score 0):

DocOpt does not support this. Trying to get it added as a feature: https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/242. If they approve, I'll port it to DocOpt.cpp.